# Using Enum item as a list index

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I Have this piece of code :

```py
class FileType(Enum):
    BASIC = 0
    BASIC_CORRUPTED = 1
    BASIC_SHITTY_END = 2
    MIMIKATZ = 3
    HASHCAT = 4

    def __eq__(self, v):
        """
        Override == in order to make `FileType.BASIC == 0` equals to True, etc.
        """
        return self.value == v if isinstance(v, int) else self.value == v.value
```

I wonder what I should add if I want to perform this: `random_array[FileType.MIMIKATZ]`. Currently, Python3 tells me `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not FileType`

Comment: Try `random_array[FileType.MIMIKATZ.value]`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your class should inherit from [**`IntEnum`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intenum) instead, this supports integer like behaviour. From the docs,

> Members of an `IntEnum` can be compared to integers; by extension,
>   integer enumerations of different types can also be compared to each
>   other:

```
from enum import IntEnum

class FileType(IntEnum):
    BASIC = 0
    BASIC_CORRUPTED = 1
    BASIC_SHITTY_END = 2
    MIMIKATZ = 3
    HASHCAT = 4
```

You can now use an enum constant to index your list,

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
data[FileType.MIMIKATZ]
# 4
```