# Python Enums: substitute `element` with `element.value`

Tags: python, enums

I have a simple `Enum`:

```py
class E(Enum):
    A = 'a'
    B = 'b'
```

To access `'a'` I must type `E.A.value`. However, the `value` is the only thing I need from the Enum object.

How to write an Enum, where `'a'` could be accessed just by `E.A`?

Comment: You can do it using `IntEnum`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56651009/4909087).

Comment: @cs95 Thank you! However, using an `int` as value was just an example. It should actually be a user-defined class. I will rewrite my question, could you please remove the `duplicate` flag?

Comment: You mean defining `A` as `self.A = 'a'` and so on?

Comment: The duplicate has been update. You need to use `self`.

Comment: Unless you you want to use `IntEnum` (which you **really shouldn't** unless you are trying to maintain compatibility with code written before the `enum` module), then you have to use `element.value`, that is simply how *enums work*. Why are you using an `enum` here? It seems like you probably want something else. Maybe an X-Y problem

Comment: The value of an enum member should only rarely be needed; can you give us more detail on the problem you are trying to solve by using an `Enum`?

Comment: [I found this answer and, while not a duplicate, it looks relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35567724/how-to-define-custom-properties-in-enumeration-in-python-javascript-like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked around a lot, and I couldn't find a good solution to this problem using the `Enum` class you're trying to use. However, if you're willing to eschew the idea of using the `Enum` as a superclass, you can kludge this together:

```
class Demo:
    # something with a 'value' method in it
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val

def custom_enum(cls):
    # class decorator to get __getattribute__() to work properly
    # this is necessary because __getattribute__() only exists as an instance method,
    #   and there seems to be no direct equivalent for class methods
    return cls()

@custom_enum
class E:
    # first, define our enumerated variables in a dict
    _enums = {
        'A': Demo('a'),
        'B': Demo('b'),
        'chicken': Demo('cluck')
    }

    # then, override __getattribute__() to first get the key from the dict, 
    #   and return the .value property of it
    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        # because of the decorator, we can't call self._enums or else we get a RecursionError
        # therefore, we need to implicitly subclass `object`, and then
        #   deliberately invoke object.__getattribute__ on self, to access _enums
        my_enums = object.__getattribute__(self, '_enums')
        return my_enums[key].value
```

Actually defining the values of your enumerable is as simple as editing the `_enums` dict. And once you've done so, it should work roughly as you want it to:

```
>>> E.A
'a'
>>> E.B
'b'
>>> E.chicken
'cluck'
```

From here you could modify the implementation however necessary (such as returning an `AttributeError` instead of a `KeyError`, for example, or overriding `__setattr__()` to make enum values non-settable, or whatever).

Comment: I posted an answer that shows how to do this with `Enum`.

Answer (score 2):

> Using an int as value was just an example. It should actually be a user-defined class.

If you mixin a class/type with the `Enum`, then simply accessing the member itself will give you a subtype of that type:

```
from enum import Enum

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

class MyEnum(MyClass, Enum):
    first = 'red'
    second = 'green'
    third = 'blue'
```

and in use:

```
>>> MyEnum.first
<MyEnum.first: 'red'>

>>> MyEnum.first.color
'red'

>>> type(MyEnum.first)
<enum 'MyEnum'>

>>> isinstance(MyEnum.first, MyClass)
True
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.